# how to show same page for any url without redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need to put a system that hosts multiple domain into maintenance.

But SEO should not affect, so I need an htaccess config that supports following use cases.

```
xyz.com/index.html - should load index page without redirect
xyz.com/products/phone.html - should load index page without redirect
xyz.com/category/sub-cat/category.html - should load index page without redirect
```

No redirect only need to load a page for any URL combination.

This is to serve same html on any URL pattern on any domain hosted on the server. So SEO bots don't get 404 error.

I tried some solutions but they are 301 redirect methods which is not what I need. I tried some other config from some other posts but did not work as expected.

Comment: _"that supports following use cases"_ - are there other URLs, that you _don't_ need to rewrite?

Comment: And why the index page? I'd much rather set up an ErrorDocument for 503 Service Unavailable ... And then have a RewriteRule for the URLs you want to be "blocked", that uses `[R=503]` to force that status code.

Comment: @CBroe I need any URL to get only 1 HTML page. Not only mentioned page. Like xyz.com/*/*/*/xyz.html or anything should see same html page.

Comment: `RewriteRule !your503errorfile - [R=503]` - any request that does not match `your503errorfile` would not get rewritten, but the status code set to 503 - and in combination with `ErrorDocument 503 your503errorfile`, that should achieve the desired effect, I think.